# idangero.us Swiper onSlideClick is not triggered when loop mode is on

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I have a problem with Swiper plugin. If you look at the example http://jsfiddle.net/Lzawws4r/ initially the onSlideClick function is triggered correctly. However, if you swipe it (try upwards), the event is not triggered at all. What might the problem be? My Swiper settings are:

```
var settings = {
    mode:'vertical',
    slidesPerView: 9,
    loop: true,

    onSlideClick: function() {
      alert('HERE');
    }
  }
```

If the loop is set to false, the problem seems to go away.

Comment: I'm having the same issues with the `onSlideChangeEnd` method. Did you manage to sort this?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working by setting `runCallbacksOnInit: false`.

The [docs](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/) say:

*Run on[Transition/SlideChange][Start/End] callbacks on swiper initialization. Such callbacks will be fired on initialization in case of your initialSlide is not 0, or you use loop mode*

Hope this helps. Seemed to fix it for me.